# How to calculate Excel PV function in Java

Tags: java, finance

This is an excel formula to calculate Present Value (PV)

```
PV (rate, nper, pmt, [fv], [type])
```

How do I calculate the same in Java with the mentioned parameters?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static double pv(double rate, double numberOfPeriod, double payment) {
    double retval = 0;
    boolean t = false;
    if (rate == 0) {
        retval = -1*((numberOfPeriod*payment));
    }
    else {
        double r1 = rate + 1;
        retval =
                (( ( 1 - Math.pow(r1, numberOfPeriod) ) / rate ) * (t ? r1 : 1)  * payment - 0) 
                /
                Math.pow(r1, numberOfPeriod);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

where t is type - When payments are due. 0 = end of period, 1 = beginning of period. The default is 0.